# datagrid search using for loop and sum up duplicate column

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, datagridview

[image: This is a sample data shown in my datagrid]

---

How is it done in c#? Just looking for Any Suggestion for this one..?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your picture represents the grid you've created,
call this method to find the duplicates:

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds the duplicates inside of a DataGridView
/// </summary>
/// <param name="grid">The instance of the DataGridView</param>
/// <param name="columnNamesToCompare">Collection of the Column.Name to compare</param>
/// <returns>List of KeyValuePairs of the index and list of it's duplicates</returns>
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>> FindDuplicates(this DataGridView grid, ICollection<string> columnNamesToCompare) {
        var dupesLog = new List<int>(); //represents rows that were marked as duplicates
        var locDupes = new List<int>(); //collector for the yield return
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Rows.Count; i++) {
            if (dupesLog.Contains(i)) continue;
            locDupes.Clear();
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.Rows.Count; j++) {
                if (j==i) continue;
                foreach (string column in columnNamesToCompare) {
                    if (grid.Rows[i].Cells[column].Value.Equals(grid.Rows[j].Cells[column].Value) == false)
                        goto _next;
                }
                //if it got to here, means it is true
                locDupes.Add(j);
                dupesLog.Add(j);
                _next:
                continue;
            }
            if (locDupes.Count > 0)
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>(i, locDupes);
        }
    }
```

There could be more efficient ways to do it, but this is what I would have done it.
I did not test it, but give it a try.